# looking for lunux screensaver

Tags: screensaver

A long time ago I was using a very cool screensaver on my ubuntu system.
Since I have to format and reinstall the system (learning linux is not without risks...).

Unfortunnaly I don't remember the name of this screen saver that I'd like to retrieve.

So if anyone know it's name, I appreciate.

This screensaver show a random slideshow for a picture's folder, but with a lot of parasites and effects like old cathodic TV screen.

It is totally useless and certainly a little bit childish but I have tried a lot of times to search it on google with many keyword, without success.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredible - how to look like an idiot...

I need to ask on this site to find the answer myself in the next minutes...
So this screen saver is XAnalogTV, a part of XScreenSaver.